# NSData from Byte array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create an `NSData` `var` from an array of bytes.

In Obj-C I might have done this:

`NSData *endMarker = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:{ 0xFF, 0xD9 }, length: 2]`

I can't figure out a working equivalent in Swift.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`NSData` has an initializer that takes a `bytes` pointer: `init(bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer <Void>, length: Int)`. An `UnsafePointer` parameter can accept a variety of different things, including a simple Swift array, so you can use pretty much the same syntax as in Objective-C. When you pass the array, you need to make sure you identify it as a `UInt8` array or Swift's type inference will assume you mean to create an `Int` array.

```
var endMarker = NSData(bytes: [0xFF, 0xD9] as [UInt8], length: 2)
```

You can read more about unsafe pointer parameters in Apple's [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) documentation.

Comment: So that's what I would have thought too. But when I print that out in the debugger I get: <ff00>; and if I do more bytes I get the same thing, all 00 after the first byte.

Comment: Added type information to the array - it was sending an array of `Int` instead of an array of `Byte`.

Comment: Just to add, `Byte` is removed in swift1.2, use `UInt8` instead.

Comment: I'm just learning Swift, so this is probably a dumb question. If I write the following: "_fileHandle!.write(NSData(bytes: UnsafePointer(byteData), length: byteLength) as Data)" then it works OK. But I'm worried that that this maybe involves creating a new copy of byteData, which is a 100 KB byte array. Surely not?

Answer (score 19):

```
var foo : Byte[] = [0xff, 0xD9]

var data = NSData(bytes: foo, length: foo.count)

println("\(data)")
```

outputs: ff d9

```
var data = NSData(bytes: [0xFF, 0xD9] as Byte[], length: 2)

println("\(data)")
```

outputs: ff d9

Edit: Ah, you have to write 'as Byte[]', so then the results are the same

---

**UPDATED for Swift 2.2**

```
var foo:[UInt8] = [0xff, 0xD9]
var data = NSData(bytes: foo, length: foo.count)
print("\(data)")
```

outputs: ff d9

```
var data = NSData(bytes: [0xFF, 0xD9] as [UInt8], length: 2)
print("\(data)")
```

outputs: ff d9

Comment: Looks like you can't use `Byte` anymore in Swift 1.2. Instead of `Byte[]`, write `[Uint8]`

Comment: No that's `UInt8` (spelling)

Answer (score 19):

You don't need to extend Data, in Swift 3 you can do this:

```
let bytes:[UInt8] = [0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03]
let data = Data(bytes: bytes)
print(data as NSData)
```

Prints "<00010203>"

To get the byte array again:

```
let byteArray:[UInt8] = [UInt8](data)
```

Comment: Thanks. Anything changed in Swift 4?

Answer (score 8):

For **Swift 5** I have created another `Data` extension that works well.

```
extension Data {

    init<T>(fromArray values: [T]) {
        var values = values
        self.init(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &values, count: values.count))
    }

    func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        let value = self.withUnsafeBytes {
            $0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: T.self)
        }
        return [T](UnsafeBufferPointer(start: value, count: self.count / MemoryLayout<T>.stride))
    }

}
```

**Sample Usage**

```
let data = Data(fromArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
let array = data.toArray(type: Int.self)
print(array)
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3 extension**

```
extension Data {

    init<T>(fromArray values: [T]) {
        var values = values
        self.init(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &values, count: values.count))
    }

    func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        return self.withUnsafeBytes {
            [T](UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: self.count/MemoryLayout<T>.stride))
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let bytes:[UInt8] = [0x00, 0xf4, 0x7c]
let data = Data(fromArray: someBytes)
print(data as NSData)

let bytes = data.toArray(type: UInt8.self)
print(bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer in Swift 5 is simple and not found here. Ran into this issue and found answer:

```
var bytes = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: 32)
let data = Data(bytes: bytes, count: bytes.count)
```