# Convert UInt8?, String, Int to String type using Swift

Tags: swift

I am using the [SwiftSocket library](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket) and I am trying to convert the data the UDP socket receives from type 'UInt8?, String, Int' to type String.

```
    let data = client.recv(1024)
    let string = NSData.withBytes(data)
    let str = NSString(data: string, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String?
```

When I attempt this I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '((UInt8]?,String,Int)' (aka'(Optional>, String, Int)') to be expected argument type '[UInt8'

If I print out 'data', i receive the following:

```
(Optional([104, 101, 108, 108, 111]), "127.0.0.1", 34835)
```

Where 104,101,108,108,111 is the string "hello".

Is there way to convert the data read to string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196820/nsdata-from-byte-array-in-swift

Comment: You have to cast it to an UInt8 Array.

Comment: in the link you posted, the answer says: var endMarker = NSData(bytes: [0xFF, 0xD9] as [UInt8], length: 2). What are FF and D9? Can you show me an example?

Comment: How would you like that data represented as a string?

Comment: in the code I gave above, I would have expected the variable str to be 'hello'

Comment: @LeoDabus the linked question is not quite what I am looking for

Comment: No. The variable 'data' contains more than just the array of bytes. Which is why none of those answers will work. I need to access the array of bytes and the provided answers may work. I am unsure of how to do that.

Comment: To access the bytes within the variable, it is 'data.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is right, but you forgot to get the data from the received object. It's `data.0`.

```
    let receivedData:([UInt8], String, Int) = ([104, 101, 108, 108, 111], "", 0)
    let data = NSData(bytes: receivedData.0, length: receivedData.0.count)
    let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

    print(str)
```